# How to cause the Wordpress web interface to update via FTP

Tags: ftp

On some installations of Wordpress, all updates performed through the administrative web interface require the FTP username and password to be entered before they take place. Others update and install themes/plugins just fine without needing FTP information. I'd like to test some permissions hunches by forcing the web administrative interface to update via FTP. Is this possible?

(**Note:** Certainly using a regular FTP client would work, but I'd like to keep the client away from as many additional steps and applications as possible. Keeping them to the web interface would make life... simpler.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with WordPress not being able to install plugins or update itself is because  WordPress uses the Apache 'user' for all its processes. In the case of Ubuntu / Linux the Apache user and group is www-data:www-data.

By doing `sudo chown www-data:www-data /wordpress` your changing the ownership of all files.

A problem can occur if *your* user account is not in the same group as `www-data` for example you FTP'd a new image to your wordpress folder and it's permissions were wrong, then it may not show up on your website. So you should also change your users Primary Group to `www-data`

Answer (score 1):

What i found is that if all the folder containing WP own to the web-user, you can install via web interface anything. In my case, Linux, my user is www-data, so i just run the next command `chown -R www-data:www-data wp-folder` where wp-folder is the folder containing my WP app (use sudo if the user is not root). And that's it. Now I can install themes and plugins directly in the web admin interface avoiding the FTP step.

Hope works for you.

Answer (score -1):

If the files & directories in your wordpress installation are all owned by the FTP user, then you can bypass the prompt for ftp username and password when updating.

Comment: Aha, I see. So in essence all updates and installations are actually taking place with FTP as the transportation method? Not HTTP? It's only when the files and permissions are set to a user other than the FTP account that the prompt appears?

Comment: @WesleyDavid I believe it's always done via FTP, but I'm not 100% sure. That's been my understanding, however.

Comment: This is incorrect, FTP is fallback.